# Calling A Function using Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Trying to pass arrays in a function. The sum is being returned as 0

```
/

void CalcAvg(int tests[], int numTests, float& avg)

{

    int sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + tests[i];
    }
avg = (float)sum/numTests;
}
```

Comment: You set it to 0 then never modified its value – what else would you expect?

Comment: You are assuming the name "sum" inside the definition of CalcAvg has a relationship with the name "sum" inside the definition of main. It doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

```
void CalcAvg(int tests[], int numTests, float& avg)
```

The sum in this function is declared locally. You need to change the function to take the sum from your main as a reference, like the average.

```
void CalcAvg(int tests[], int numTests, float& avg, int& sum)
```

Or change the CalcAvg function to return the sum, shown below.

```
int CalcAvg(int tests[], int numTests, float& avg)
{
  int sum=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++)
  {
      sum = sum + tests[i];
  }
  avg = (float)sum/numTests;
  return sum;
}
```

Then in your main set sum equal to `CalcAvg`

```
int main(){
    ...
    sum = CalcAvg (tests, 6, avg);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the `sum` variable with the value you calculate as sum in `CalcAvg` (I altered your `CalcAvg` func to return the sum)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//prototype (fixed to return the sum)
int CalcAvg(int tests[], int numTests, float& avg);

int main ()
{

    int tests[6]; //array declaration
    float avg;
    int sum=0;

    //input test scores
    cout<<"Enter"<<6<<"test scores:"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        cout<<"enter Test"<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>tests[i];
    }

    //2.print first test score

    cout<<tests[0]<<endl;

    //3.print the last test score

    cout<<tests[5]<<endl;

    //4.print all test scores

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        cout<<tests[i]<<endl;
    }

    //7. Calculate Sum & Avg using function

    sum = CalcAvg (tests, 6, avg);

    cout<<"Your sum is"<<sum<<" and your average is "<<avg<<endl;

return 0;
}

int CalcAvg(int tests[], int numTests, float& avg)

{

    int sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + tests[i];
    }
avg = (float)sum/numTests;
return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem of "scope"

Note that the `sum` in CalcAvg is separate from the `sum` in main.

Answer (score 0):

first I must ask you why use `cout<<"Enter"<<6<<"test scores:"<<endl;` insted of `cout<<"Enter 6 test scores:"<<endl;`

you declered sum within a function. ic c++ it creates the variable in the function and it is destroyes at end of the function. do you think the `sum` you declared within the main function is changed through CalcAvg function. to do this you should rerurn a pointer to `sum` in the function if you wante to change the value which you declared in main().

or use a return statment to return the sum within CalcAvg function.

Answer (score 0):

see this example to notice how to change a value from a function using pointers.

```
main(){
  int x=5;      
  change(&x);
  cout<<x;
  }

void change(int *p){
   *p=10;
  }
```